# Primer react-octicons included twice w/ webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm building a react app that includes GitHub's Primer https://primer.style/, in this case Primer's react components and react octicons.

I'm using named exports for a small number of octicons so I would expect them to be rather small:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { MarkGithubIcon, CodeIcon, EyeIcon, DotFillIcon, CheckIcon, StopIcon } from '@primer/octicons-react';
import { Box, Flex, Button, Text, TextInput, Label, BorderBox, Link, ButtonPrimary, Avatar } from '@primer/components';
```

After using Webpack's chunckSplitting and using externals for React I still end up with a rather large vendor bundle. What startles me is the fact that the react-octions/index.esm.js seems to be included again in full size. Any ideas?

[image]

My webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        linter: './src/linter.js',
        console: './src/console.js',
        documentor: './src/documentor.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/assets/js',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    mode: "production",
    devtool: '',
    externals: {
        'react': 'React', // Case matters here
        'react-dom': 'ReactDOM' // Case matters here
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((?!(codemirror)).*)[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: For now it import all icons. There are open PR about this https://github.com/primer/octicons/pull/335

Comment: Thanks @demkovych, I thought that this was addressed in Octicons 10.0.0 that was released a few weeks ago: "If you were to compile this example with a tool that supports tree-shaking (such as Webpack, Rollup, or Parcel) the resulting bundle would only include the "zap" and "beaker" icons." https://primer.style/octicons/packages/react